# Provide both :value and v-model on a radio type field

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
<input type="radio" :value="myValue" v-model="value" />
```

I'm trying to create a radio button and wrap it in a component, so `value` becomes a variable. The problem is that I'm getting the following error:

```
:value="myValue" conflicts with v-model on the same element because the latter already expands to a value binding internally
```

I've tried to replace `v-model` with direct bindings but I cannot replicate the same functionality. Why does this error appear in this case? This is taken directly from official docs for the radio buttons.

Comment: why are you using value and v-model? v-model is sufficient

Comment: what do you wamt/expect to happen if `myValue` and `value` are different?

Comment: Hm, the thing is that it accepts the value that is currently checked. If `myValue` and `value` are the same, the radio button is selected, otherwise it's not selected.

Comment: What do you _**want**_ to happen if `value` is `false` and `myValue` is `true`? Should the radio button be checked or not? I'm trying to show you that what you've constructed makes no sense.

Comment: It works fine for me though... https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-haslett-x4dis

Comment: Hm, that's true, there is some logic error there, thanks. I took it from `https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Radio` however, official docs suggest it's ok to do it in this case.

Comment: Also, right, it works fine for me too, it's just that the new version of vue-loader for webpack shows an error that it's not allowed. It also doesn't really make much sense to implement it like that, as @StephenThomas pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

`v-model` is just shorthand for `:value="someVar" @input="someVar = $event"`. meaning you are assigning the value twice. Depending on your need you can do `:value="someVar"` and then have a custom function handle the input like so:
`@input="someFunc"` this function would accept the input (by default) and then you could update `myVar` as you desire.
See [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Basic-Usage) for a more detailed explanation